# How do you exclude a file from MSE?

Tags: ms-security-essentials

Microsoft Security Essentials has decided that a vbs script I wrote is a vbs/genmalone virus. How can I exclude that file from MSE without excluding everything in its folder or excluding all vbs files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the Microsoft Security Essentials application (Start > Search for "Microsoft Security Essentials"). Next, switch to the `Settings` tab, locate `Excluded files and locations`, and select it.

[image]

Browse to the files/folders you wish to exclude and save the changes.